# Observable List Cast/Conversion

Tags: java, observablelist

I'm fairly new to Java, and am working to get my head wrapped around the ObservableList.

I have an observable list of type WebHistory.Entry (from the WebView/WebEngine.) I want to have an observable list of type String that simply has the URLs of each item in the original ObservableList. (WebHistory.Entry.getUrl()). This is so I can pass it to a ComboBox (that is of type String). Almost like a wrapper on top of the other list.

Is there any easy way to create an observable list that is a little more elegant than just iterating through the list like so:

```
for (Entry e : webHistory.getEntries()) {
    //...add to a list here...
}
```

Any tips on how I could go about approaching it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

First

```
override *YourClass* method `toString()` as 
public String toString(){
 return this.URLFIELD;
}
```

After

```
ObservableList<YourClass> list;
list=FXCollections.observableArrayList(YourClassInstance.getEntries()); //or simile
cmb.setItems(list);
```

The ComboBox, in this case, is populated as *"for all entries get YourClassInstance.toString()"* (`getURL()`)

**This is a JavaFX example**